# Por que não consigo recuperar a cor de fundo com o dom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando recuperar a cor da minha div porém não consigo, gostaria de saber o por que isso está ocorrendo

Meu código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        #conteudo{
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: #610B38;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="conteudo">oi</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let div = document.getElementById('conteudo')
        console.log(div.style.backgroundColor)
    </script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cor do background desse elemento está definido no CSS; não é uma propriedade do elemento, por isso obviamente quando você acessa a propriedade `backgroundColor` ela está vazia.

Para recuperar o estilo computado do elemento, você precisa utilizar a função `getComputedStyle` dessa maneira:

```
let div = document.getElementById('conteudo')
console.log(getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor)
```